# Restricting system resources in wsgi

Tags: python, django, signals, mod-wsgi

I am running Django in a mod_wsgi environment on a shared host. I want to restrict the resources a request can use and ideally raise an Exception if it exceeds that amount. The WSGI options are as follows:

```
WSGIRestrictSignal off
WSGIRestrictStdout off
```

The VirtualHost has the following:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess django processes=10 threads=1 display-name=django-web
WSGIProcessGroup django
```

In the request I do the following:

```
signal.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU, (10, -1))
signal.signal(signal.SIGXCPU, cpu_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_signal)
signal.alarm(1)
#Do some stuff
signal.alarm(0)
```

However when I run the request I get the error signal only works in main thread despite when I print out the number of active threads and the thread name I get there is one thread and the current thread name is MainThread so i don't understand why Python tries to set the signal it doesn't believe its running in the main thread.

I am running Python 2.7.2, Django 1.3.1 Apache 2.2.21 and WSGI 3.3

Comment: Describe your goal, for example "I would like to restrict <some_resource> consumption to <some_threshold>".

Answer (score 0):

Send an email to mod_wsgi mailing list and will discuss there what is possible. In mod_wsgi 4.0 dev version there are some experimental mechanisms for killing process when CPU usage exceeds some value, but it is process wide. Doing it on a per request basis is hard because of multithreading being able to be used. Here on stackoverflow is not the place to be holding a discussion about it.